# bash $(printf "%s\n") does not create multiline

Tags: bash

I created shell script, that logs into FTP server and renames some directories. I put FTP commands in multiline string like so

```
# !/bin/sh

ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
$COMMANDS
bye
EOF
```

the `$COMMANDS` contains commands separated by new line. This approach works, when I construct command like so

```
NL=$'\n'
COMMANDS="command one$NL"
COMMANDS+="command two$NL"
COMMANDS+="command three"
```

I firstly tried populate `$COMMANDS` with function `printf`, but even after several trials, I was unsuccessful. The expression

```
COMMANDS="$(printf "%s\n" "command one" "command two" "command three")"
```

evaluated to string with blank spaces between commands and when used in script as FTP command, it was processed as single line.

I tried replace `\n` with `\r` which results in variable `$COMMANDS` not beeing populated with any string.

Can someone more educated *please* explain to me, whats the problem with `printf` function here?

## Update

I've manage how to achieve my goal via rsync, so the FTP approach I've abandoned, but I'm still curious why this happens.

Problem is with storing `printf` in variable. I made test script:

```
echo "==== printf directly"
printf "%s\n" "foo" "bar" "baz"

echo "==== stored in variable"
VAR_1=$(printf "%s\n" "foo" "bar" "baz")
echo $VAR_1
```

running `./test.sh` outputs

```
==== printf directly
foo
bar
baz
==== stored in variable
foo bar baz
```

setting `IFS=$'\n'` does not help.

## Update 2

I can get multiline from variable if I wrap it in double qotes

```
echo "$VAR_1"
```

but I'm unable to get the same result if used inside heredoc

```
echo `cat <<EOF
$VAR_1
"$VAR_1"
EOF`
```

I get output

```
foo bar baz "foo bar baz"
```

note: there is even no newline between the two variable outputs in heredoc, which is also strange to me.

Comment: I think you have to mess with IFS (set it to \n only, not leave it to be the default \n or tab or space) to get it right

Comment: What is your `/bin/sh`? Is it a symlink to `bash`?

Comment: A word of advice: trying to do this with strings, command line ftp, and bash, is unlikely to work even if you get past this hurdle (been there, done that etc.).  You should give serious consideration to using 'expect', or using some other language with an FTP library (e.g. python).

Comment: Or use a command line FTP client such as `lftp`

Comment: for what it's worth, the `printf` thing works fine here.

Comment: @cuonglm here is [perfect explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: @Vaclav: I mean what is your `/bin/sh` link to? `/bin/bash` or anything else?

Comment: @cuonglm my scripting provider is `dash` (running debian/wheezy)

Comment: @Vaclav: So you need quote your variable `"$COMMANDS"` and later solution won't work. `$'\n'` does not work in `dash`.

Answer (score 2):

When you do not use quotes, word splitting will split the string on  any whitespace (by default), and `echo` will join the split parts with spaces. In effect, this will "eat" the newlines.

You already found the improvement

```
echo "$VAR_1"
```

Now do the same for the here-document:

```
echo "`cat <<EOF
$VAR_1
EOF`"
```

Edit: Not `echo` was eating the newlines, it was the shell.

Comment: It's not echo doing it, the shell does wordsplitting after parameter expansion for command arguments.

Comment: Technically `$(cmd)` or the deprecated `\`cmd\` ` form strip *all* trailing newline characters,  and when those are unquoted in list context (such as in arguments to a simple command like `echo`), they are subject to split+glob, and the newline character happens to be in the default value of `$IFS`. So upon expansion (not *parsing*), the string will be split into separate arguments to `echo` and `echo` happens to print its arguments space-separated (and followed by *one* newline character).